# Get number of in time deliveries according to specific customer hour in SQL

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, rate

I've 2 SQL tables:

The first is called `LIVRAISON` and stores all deliveries. It especially contains the customer's number (`NumCptClient`), date and time of the delivery (`heureLiv`, `DateLiv`) and the town name where the customer has been delivered (`nomVille`).

The second is called `IMPERATIF` that modelize a special service to clients wanting to be delivered before a given hour. That special service stands by a customer's number, a town name, the maximal hour when the customer must be delivered (`heureImp`) and start/end date of that premium option (`dateDebImp`, `dateFinImp`) : a delivery enters in the special service field when it matchs an `IMPERATIF` row by a `NumCptClient` AND `nomVille` combination and that its date is in the date range of that row (a customer, although having special service's orders, can be delivered in a town not concerned and vice versa: that kind of deliveries musn't be taken in account here).

I need to compute by a single and fast SQL query the rate between the number of deliveries that satisfied this special service (`heureLiv` <= `heureImp`) and the total number of deliveries for each couple of customer AND town concerned by this premium option.

I'd tailored that request that gives me all needed info except the rate:

```
SELECT NumCptCli, nomVille, heureImp, COUNT(*) AS TotalLivs
FROM LIVRAISON
  NATURAL JOIN IMPERATIF
GROUP BY NumCptCli, nomVille
```

Then, the question is fondamentally, how to change that query so as to add a column with the corresponding rate, that is `livsAlheure` column below, and without display special service's couples that haven't any corresponding delivery registered yet?

```
NumCptCli |nomVille            |heureImp|TotalLivs |livsAlheure
----------|--------------------|--------|----------|-----------
12345678  |PARIS               |07:30   |311       |80.56
87654321  |BREST               |15:30   |314       |95.2
...
```

Comment: add a tag of the sql language you're using

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should stop using `natural join` - it considers join columns by **name** not based on foreign keys and can quickly lead to completely wrong joins. Your `GROUP BY` usage is also invalid standard SQL - you have to include `heruimp` in the `group by` clause.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Natural join is dangerous. Forget about that construction!

Comment: the DBMS is `mysql` - I've added it

Comment: primary keys of `IMPERATIF` are only `numCptCli` and `nomVille`, explaining the `GROUP BY` limited to these attributes